# MS Access - VBA to select multiple listbox items

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, multi-select

I am using Access 2013.

I have an Access form that has multiple select listbox populated from another table and being saved to multi valued field.

I am selecting some values in multiselect listbox depending on a value of another field.

I can do this with the following code.

```
Private Sub Combo23_AfterUpdate()
    Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox.ListCount - 1
            If (Me.ListBox.Column(4, i) = "Criteria") Then
                Me.ListBox.Selected(i) = True
                End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

This code Works OK, but does not save to the bound field. When i change the record and come nothing seems to be selected.

But if i select some values manually after runing VBA it updates the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: This code only selects items in a listbox, where is the code that actually saves the values? Where is the code for "When i change the record"?  Do you save it before you change the record?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to select them in the first place, or is the end result possible without selection?